# Date is invalid in Chrome with ISO format - tested with: 2012-11-31

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

> Who will answer my question?
>
> ### How can I validate a date using Javascript cross browser?

I use a invalid date: 2011-11-31 like below:

```
var d = new Date("2012-11-31")
```

#### In FF:

```
d = NaN // Date is invalid
```

#### In Chrome:

```
d.getFullYear();//2012
d.getDate();//1
d.getMonth();//11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested in IE7-9, chrome, opera, safari, firefox. Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/MRwAq/

You could do it like this:

```
(function(){
                             //This should be good enough initial filter, let the native Date decide if the number are valid
    var validStringRE = /^([0-9]{4})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9])$/;

    function pad( num ) {
    return num < 10 ? "0"+num : num;
    }

    Date.prototype.getISOFormat = function(){
    return this.getFullYear() + "-" +
    pad( ( this.getMonth() + 1 ) ) + "-" +
    pad( this.getDate() );
    };

    function isValidISODate( date ) {
    var matches, a;
        if( !validStringRE.test( date.toString() ) ) {
        return false; //Get rid of anything but "NNNN-NN-NN"
        }

    matches = date.match( validStringRE );

    a = new Date( +matches[1], +matches[2] - 1, +matches[3], 0, 0, 0, 0 );

        if( isNaN( a ) ) {
        return false; //firefox, ie
        }

        if( a.toString().toLowerCase() === "invalid date" ) {
        return false; //chrome in some cases, opera, safari
        }

    return a.getISOFormat() === date; //browsers that "conveniently" calculate
    }

window.isValidISODate = isValidISODate;
})()
```

Then:

```
var isValid = isValidISODate("2012-11-31");
//false

var isValid = isValidISODate("2012-11-30");
//true
```

Comment: Why 2011-11-32 is invalid in Chrome, but not for 2011-11-31?

Comment: @vietean ? `new Date("2011-11-31").getISOFormat() === "2011-11-31";
//false` and `new Date("2011-11-32").getISOFormat() === "2011-11-32";
//false`

Comment: @vietan, yes this is in chrome or any browser that would take ISO string in the constructor in the first place.

Comment: this fails for all dates for me. you want to use this.getUTCMonth() and this.getUTCDate() otherwise input is assumed UTC and output is local

Comment: @Mr.Mindor, it is certainly not a bug. That is far too presumptuous.

Comment: It will make another issue in FF, because: new Date("2011-11-31") = NaN => is not Date obj => could not call function getISOFormat. :)

Comment: Thanks for your updating. I love it.

Comment: @vietean for the NaN issue, add a function...`function isDateValid(dateString) {
var date = new Date(dateString);
if ( date = NaN) return false;
return  (new Date(dateString).getISOFormat()===dateString);
};`

Comment: @davin, so far in my testing all browsers that support iso format strings (strictly YYYY-MM-DD, 0 padded, no spaces etc) it will return true for valid dates that actually exist.

Comment: @vietaen, I have now what I believe is cross-browser.. tested in safari, ie7, opera and chrome

Answer (score 1):

You can't reliably do that. See section 15.9.4.2 of [the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf):

> The function first attempts to parse the format of the String
>   according to the rules called out in Date Time String Format
>   (15.9.1.15). If the String does not conform to that format the
>   function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or
>   implementation-specific date formats.

Essentially, if you enter an invalid date, the language can do whatever it wants, i.e. give back `NaN` or try and "fix" it as it sees fit.

Esailija posted a pragmatic way to test that seems to work well.

Comment: 15.9.1.15 lists "YYYY-MM-DD" as a valid format. it also specifies `Unrecognisable Strings or dates containing **illegal element values** in the format String shall cause Date.parse to return NaN.` (emphasis mine) 11-31 would indicate an illegal value.

Comment: @Mr.Mindor, you're still wrong. Read that entire section carefully, illegal element values and unrecognisable formats are mentioned after implementation-dependencies, i.e. if the format fits neither the ISO8601, nor implementation-defined formats, and is thus unrecognisable, then it will return `NaN`. So if an implementation defines that as a valid format, it isn't illegal, and so it doesn't have to return `NaN`.

Comment: are you contending that 'YYYY-MM-DD' is not a valid ISO8601 format?
15.9.1.15 ... `This format includes date-only forms: YYYY YYYY-MM YYYY-MM-DD` If it is valid it should not fall back to implementation specifics.

Comment: or are you contending that 2011-11-31 does not contain illegal element values? 
also 15.9.1.15 `Illegal values (out-of-bounds as well as syntax errors)` 
(31 is in bounds for some months but not for others)
Or are you contending that since 2011-11-31 is not a valid date it is not valid ISO8601 and so the implementation can do with it as it pleases and decide that 11-31 is an illegal value?

Comment: @Mr.Mindor, the third one more or less. Since it isn't valid 8601 it can try and make it valid in its own way (you wrote illegal when I think you meant to write legal).

Comment: err that should have read 'that 11-31 is not an illegal value?'
So feature of Chrome that it treats all months as having 31 days that may overlap into the following month. "2011-2-31" is treated like "2011-03-03" I suppose it is at least consistent.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5509/discussion-between-mr-mindor-and-davin)